# Using GroupBy and Max in LINQ Lambda Expressions

Tags: linq, select, lambda, group-by, max

I have a collection, for example:

```
**id1, id2, value**
   1    9    12
   2    9     6
   3    11    8
   4    11   87
```

I want to use LINQ and get the following result:

```
**value**
   6
   87
```

P.S.

```
id1 - select MAX;
id2 - group column;
```

I need an answer in the form of

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.id2).select(s=>s.value);
```

I hope for your help.

Comment: You haven't expressed your question clearly at all. *Why* would you expect the results to be 6 and 87? Why are you grouping by id1 when every row has a different id1? If you were grouping by id2 that would make more sense, but then the results should be 12 and 87, not 6 and 87. Please take some time to make your question clear.

Comment: But `6 < 12` and `87 > 8`; please explain.

Comment: I think he wants to group by id2 and select Max Value from each group

Comment: @anouar.bag: That's what I suspect too, but if so the question has been written very carelessly.

Comment: should your expected result be 12 and 87?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, now we've got a slightly clearer set of requirements (though still far from clearly written) the simplest approach would probably be:

```
var maxes = list.GroupBy(x => x.id2,
                         (key, xs) => xs.OrderByDescending(x => x.id1)
                                        .First()
                                        .value);
```

Unfortunately LINQ doesn't provide a simple way of getting "the element with the maximal value" (instead of the maximal value itself). I have a method in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) which does this though, called `MaxBy`:

```
var maxes = list.GroupBy(x => x.id2,
                         (key, xs) => xs.MaxBy(x => x.id2).value);
```

---

**Original answer** (Grouping by id2, taking the maximum value)

I'm answering *assuming* you actually meant to group by `id2` rather than `id1`, and you actually wanted the results of 12 and 87 rather than 6 and 87. In that case, you'd want:

```
var maxes = list.GroupBy(x => x.id2, (id, xs) => xs.Max(x => x.value));
```

Or (possibly simpler to understand):

```
var maxes = list.GroupBy(x => x.id2)
                .Select(xs => xs.Max(x => x.value));
```

Or:

```
var maxes = list.GroupBy(x => x.id2, x => x.value)
                .Select(values => values.Max());
```

Or:

```
var maxes = list.GroupBy(x => x.id2,     // Key selector
                         x => x.value,   // Element selector
                         (key, values) => values.Max()); // Result selector
```

Or even:

```
var maxes = list.GroupBy(x => x.id2)
                .Select(xs => xs.Select(x => x.value).Max());
```

As you can see, [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) has lots of overloads :)

Or you could use a query expression:

```
var maxes = from x in list
            group x.value by x.id2 into values
            select values.Max();
```

You shouldn't restrict yourself to *either* query expressions or the extension method version - it's important to understand both, so you can use whatever's most appropriate.

Comment: id1 - select MAX;
id2 - group column;

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I have to choose VALUE for each id2 where id1 - MAX

Comment: @PavelIvanov: Okay, I *think* I see what you mean, but you should really put more effort into making this clear in the future. See my edit for an answer which hopefully solves this...

Comment: I had to change the First() call in the first snippet to FirstOrDefault(). Entity Framework threw a NotSupportedException for First().

Answer (score 6):

Apparently OP wants the `Value` with maximum `Id1` within `Id2`:

Sample data:

```
public class Row
{
    public int Id1;
    public int Id2;
    public int Value;
}

List<Row> rows = new List<Row>(){
    new Row(){Id1=1,Id2=9,Value=12},
    new Row(){Id1=2,Id2=9,Value=6},
    new Row(){Id1=3,Id2=11,Value=8},
    new Row(){Id1=4,Id2=11,Value=87}
};
```

Solution:

```
List<int> res = rows.GroupBy(r => r.Id2)
                    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(i=>i.Id1).First().Value)
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps others, I had a similar situation except multiple records needed to be returned instead of a single record.

Eg.

```
**id1, id2, value**
   1    9    12
   2    9     6 <-
   2    9     7 <-
   3    11    8
   4    11   87 <-
   4    11   88 <-
```

The following returns the above four records as two lists of two records (enumerable of enumerables):

```
 var maxes = from x in list
            group x by x.id2 into xs
            select new {values = xs.Where(x => x.id1 == xs.Max(y => y.id1))};
```

or

```
 var maxes = list.GroupBy(x => x.id2,
            (key, xs) => new
            {
                values = xs.Where(x => x.id1 == xs.Max(y => y.id1))
            });
```